# Bundle SSL certificate with APK and IPA files

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-security

I have a scenario where the Worklight server is SSL enabled and my app is on Android and Iphone. 
Is there a way to bundle the SSL certificate with APK and IPA files itself so that the user need not do extra actions to get hold of the certificates?
Note: This is not WL Adapters connecting to external HTTPS components. This is between WL client and WL server (SSL enabled)

Answer (score 0):

While this procedure may be possible in an iOS or Android application, it is however not a path supported in a Worklight-based application for iOS or Android.